# genfromtxt only imports first column, after changing dtype

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am importing huge data sets with various types of data, using genfromtxt.
My original code worked fine (ucols is the list of columns I want to load):

`data = np.genfromtxt(fname,comments = '#', skip_header=1, usecols=(ucols))`

Some of my values are strings, so to avoid getting entries of NaN I tried setting `dtype = None` :

```
        data = np.genfromtxt(fname, dtype = None,comments = '#', skip_header=1, usecols=(ucols))
```

Now for some reason I only get one column of data, IE the first column. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I now understand I am supposed to obtain a 1D structured array that can be referenced to get a whole row of values. However I wish to have my data as a numpy array, is it possible to use genfromtxt with dtype = None and still obtain a numpy array instead of a structured array, or alternatively is there a quick way to convert between the two. Although the second method is not preferable unless it can be quick and efficient since I am moving much larger values than this current instance usually.

Comment: Actually, you can define a list of types for ```dtype``` whose length must equal the number of columns used, such as ```dtype = (float, str, int, float)``` for 4 columns.

Comment: I do not necessarily know the data types of the input data

Comment: With `dtype=None` it should create a structured array, 1d, but with as many fields as your `usecols` specifies.  Your description of `one column of data...` is unclear.  Be more explicit.

Comment: So in my case usecols is a list of size 289 values, which is what I want. The data is of size (1989,289) and the inputted data is only of size (1989,). This is what I mean when I say only one column of data is inputted (the first column of the data set).

Comment: What's the `dtype` of the loaded array?

Comment: It is mixed: first column is integer, majority are floats, second to last and fourth to last columns are strings

Comment: That's what a structured array with a compound dtype looks like.

Comment: I understand now what you mean, however is there another way to retain data types but not having a structured array with fields, but just being a regular numpy array of the proper size?

Comment: A numpy array always has a `dtype`. Normally that dtype is numeric is string.  This compound is one generalization.  `object` is another, making the array more `list` like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a structured array and write it to csv:

```
In [131]: arr=np.ones((3,), dtype='i,f,U10,i,f')
In [132]: arr['f2']=['a','bc','def']
In [133]: arr
Out[133]: 
array([(1, 1., 'a', 1, 1.), (1, 1., 'bc', 1, 1.), (1, 1., 'def', 1, 1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<U10'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<f4')])
In [134]: np.savetxt('test',arr,fmt='%d,%e,%s,%d,%f')
In [135]: cat test
1,1.000000e+00,a,1,1.000000
1,1.000000e+00,bc,1,1.000000
1,1.000000e+00,def,1,1.000000
```

load all columns with dtype=None:

```
In [137]: np.genfromtxt('test',delimiter=',',dtype=None,encoding=None)
Out[137]: 
array([(1, 1., 'a', 1, 1.), (1, 1., 'bc', 1, 1.), (1, 1., 'def', 1, 1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<U3'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<f8')])
```

load a subset of the columns:

```
In [138]: np.genfromtxt('test',delimiter=',',dtype=None,encoding=None,usecols=
     ...: (1,2,4))
Out[138]: 
array([(1., 'a', 1.), (1., 'bc', 1.), (1., 'def', 1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<U3'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```

Comment: Although I have tried this code, and it does indeed work in the Ipython console, for my script it doesn't tell me what I am doing wrong or why I am getting my error. Can you please clarify

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or just something that you don't expect?  Note that my `Out[137]` has shape (3,), not (3,5).

Comment: Not an error message just not what I expect, so i expect all 289 columns to be in the input but I only always get only the first column of all data sets I input.